# laravel mpdf: Save into database after streaming

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

so I'm trying to create a pdf, using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf library and then save the result as a .pdf file in Storage and save the name in a database in order to re-access it later and make a Show and E-mail functions.
The logic will be something like this.

```
  elseif ($request->type =='full_time') {
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('employee.contract_full_pdf', ['request'=>$request]);

    $name = 'contract'.time().$request->id.'.'.'.pdf';
    Storage::put($name, $pdf);
    $employee->contract= $name;

    return $pdf->stream ('full-time_contract.pdf');
    }
```

Any help or tips on how to approaches this and also the best practices information will be appreciated!

Note: the $pdf->Output('Filename', 'F'); method didn't work for me and didn't store the file, didn't throw an error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pdf->save()` to save your pdf to file. I modified little bit of your code.

```
elseif ($request->type =='full_time') {
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('employee.contract_full_pdf',['request'=>$request]);

    // there is extra 'dot' that I removed
    $name = 'contract'.time().$request->id.'.pdf';

    // to save to storage folder
    $pdf->save(storage_path($name));

    // save filename to database
    $employee->contract= $name;
    $employee->save();

    return $pdf->stream ('full-time_contract.pdf');
}
```